# Using .Get() in a foreach versus generating a list beforehand C#

Tags: c#, performance, list

I have a question regarding performance that I'm curious about. Is it better (performance, not opinion wise) to do the below:

```
    foreach (var Obj in SomeData.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
      // Do work
    }
```

Or should one do something like the below instead?

```
List<object> DataProperties = SomeData.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var Obj in DataProperties)
{
// Do work
}
```

(Which either could also be a (int i = 0; i < [Object].Count; i++) too, I'm not sure if that affects performance as far as using the index versus the object itself)

I would assume the .GetType().GetProperties() enumerator will take some overhead if calling it each time, but will it create more overhead than creating a list and enumerating the object properties once? Or in the end (on a large scale) does the variable performance difference so small that either way would be fine?

I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are identical.  There would be no difference in performance.  System.Type.GetProperties() returns `PropertyInfo[]`, not `List<object>`.  It would be more expensive to construct a `List<object>` from `PropertyInfo[]`, e.g. `DataProperties = new List<object>(SomeData.GetType().GetProperties());` would have additional overhead.

Comment: Why is that @Tim?

Comment: @peter in both examples, GetProperties() is called once, and the `IEnumerable` interface is used exactly the same way.  Performance is the same whether or not you store a temporary reference.

Comment: I know. Its always helpful to add a bit of explanation when one states a fact

Comment: Interesting, so even though the enumerator is called multiple times via the .GetType().GetProperties() (while in a for loop) method, it only acts as a single call (as in it's not re-grabbing the list/recalling the method each time the loop passes through)? If that's the case, I suppose I just misunderstood how the enumerator was used in that manner. Either way thanks for clearing it up!